# MKMapView memory management

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, mkmapview

I am using `MKMapView` in Objective-C. App is taking 45MB memory, but when `MKMapView` appears memory usage increases up to 110 MB.
This is not good iPhone 4 and iPhone 4S.

Please suggest me code structure for optimize memory.

Comment: Are you measuring memory usage on device or simulator?

Answer (score 10):

Well working with `MKMapKit` need to be careful about **Memory Management**. Especially if you are using `UITabbarController` and setting `MapView` in any of the view controller.

If you need to use `MKMapKit` in your application i would recommend you to initialise `MapView` in `viewWillAppear` and remove from Superview in `viewDidDisappear`. Also you need to remove it's delegate `mapView.delegate = nil` and make `MapView = nil` before removing from Superview.

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    mapView.delegate = nil;
    [mapView removeFromSuperview];
    mapView = nil;
}
```

**swift**

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    mapView.delegate = nil
    mapView.removeFromSuperview()
    mapView = nil
}
```

By doing this all you memory occupied by map will be free.

**Please do not add `MapView` in your `ViewController` in Storyboard or xib. Create MapView Programmatically.**

Hope it helps you with Memory Management with MKMapKit.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using iOS 9 ?

I do this and I have no memory issues with my maps - in iOS 8 and below this was an issue and there are many threads on this topic.

So if you are in iOS 9, do this and see if it helps.

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    mapView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: thank for reply, but i have did that still memory issue.while ViewController is popOut and this viewDidDisappear will called but memonry is still same 110 MB

Comment: As long when you push and pop the memory doesn't keep climbing up. Previously (pre iOS 9) i would push / pop and the memory would climb and climb until crash. I just did a test with my app in simulator. App first load = 22 mb, present map 180-200 mb, pop map (modal view) down to 110mb. Repeat process, 180 = show map, 110 remove. Before it would go 180, 250, 300, 400 etc ... crash. I did this 20x in a row - no crash so I assume this is as good as it gets. Before, 10 times repeat process then I would get a crash.

Comment: I also follow the same step and try to create map view programmatically, avoid creating from storyboard and it will fix your issue